# Magento: get value of billing[use_for_shipping] in shipping_method/available.phtml

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

In the file `shipping_method/available.phtml`,  is there any way to get the value of the radio button: `billing[use_for_shipping]` which appears on the Checkout Onepage billing.phtml page.  ?

I have a custom option added to the `billing[use_for_shipping]` radio button group and I want to remove certain shipping options based on what the user selected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is

```
$quote->getBillingAddress()->getUseForShipping();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->getSameAsBilling();
```